# Ошибка JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION

Tags: android

Приложение работает на всех версиях android, кроме 8.
Приложение просто вылетает.
Вот лог.

```html
09-19 21:04:19.929 26391-26391/ru.****** W/ResourceType: Bad string block: string #196 is not null-terminated
    CREATING STRING CACHE OF 35672 bytes
    Bad string block: string #196 decoded length is not correct -1 vs 31660
09-19 21:04:19.962 26391-26391/ru.***** A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: chars == null && char_count > 0
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]     in call to NewString
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]     from java.lang.String[] android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(int)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x7241d168 self=0x797eac2a00
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | sysTid=26391 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7a03a989a8
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | state=R schedstat=( 1150556172 95733606 616 ) utm=111 stm=4 core=0 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | stack=0x7fd4f89000-0x7fd4f8b000 stackSize=8MB
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #00 pc 00000000003c9d6c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+208)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #01 pc 000000000049a018  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+348)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #02 pc 00000000002fccf4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1048)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #03 pc 00000000002fd1d4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+180)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #04 pc 000000000037a808  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+992)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #05 pc 000000000010200c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+664)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #06 pc 000000000012225c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #07 pc 000000000048a624  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_content_res_AssetManager_getArrayStringResource__I+132)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceStringArray(AssetManager.java:208)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:573)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at ru.nextgenstudio.securityexam.fragments.DiFragment.onCreate(DiFragment.java:54)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2489)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1237)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2407)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2186)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2142)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2043)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:719)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]
```

Нашел от куда идет проблема

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    heads = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.di_heads);
    bodies = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.di_bodies);
    isLargeText = activity.isLargeText();
```

di_bodies берет ресурс с XML.

```
<string-array name="di_heads">
    <item><![CDATA[<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;*********]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;*********]]></item>
</string-array>
```

И когда количество знаков в   превышает 19300 Приложение вылетает на Android 8, но на версиях ниже  все работает.

Дальнейшее копание привело что android/sdk/sources/android-27/android/text/HTML.java 
КУча ошибок

А там же в adndroid -24 этих ошибок нет

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: У вас есть сишные вставки/либы в коде? Или все на чистом Java?

Comment: нет вставок, делаю в андройд студио. Аналогичные работают но почему то именно в нем загвоздка

Comment: Определил из за чего выходит ошибка.

Comment: @АндрейТовтин тогда напишите об этом в ответе. Возможно, решение пригодиться кому-нибудь ещё, кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev еще не нашел как исправить прошу помощи

Comment: В [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878650/android-indexoutofbound-exception-for-resource-getstring) у человека другая ошибка, но те же симптомы. Похоже, что начиная с Android 8 строковые ресурсы имеют ограничение на длину, но это не документировано. Видимо, вам придётся выносить содержимое в отдельные файлы в `assets/` или `res/raw/` и работать с ними.

Comment: Ну, или можно попытаться отправить [багрепорт](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs).